# SQL Return the date on which the sold 10 products passes per parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

Hello i need to know when (date) the 10 (tenth) item as been sold, the ID item is passed per parameter,
this is the sales tables:

[image: Sales table and Sales Line table]

Thks in advance

Comment: LOL ! Nice question and nice screenshot editing.

Comment: what you dont understand?

Comment: Eoin, is for sql server, sorry, i try s select but i dont know who i count 10 items

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the 10th row in `Vendas` table ordered by Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following (I believe* that I used the correct columns):

```
// This example finds the date that the 10th occurrence of Part #1001 was sold.

// @idArtigo is the placeholder for your incoming parameter
DECLARE @idArtigo int;
SET @idArtigo = 1001;

WITH Artigos AS (
    SELECT
        Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY v.[DataHora] ASC, lv.[IdLinhaVenda] ASC) AS RowNumber,
        v.[DataHora],
        v.[IdVenda],
        lv.[IdLinhaVenda]
    FROM
        [Vendas] AS v
        INNER JOIN [LinhasVenda] AS lv
            ON ( v.[IdVenda] = lv.[IdVenda] )
    WHERE
        lv.[IdArtigo] = @idArtigo
)
SELECT
    [DataHora],
    [IdVenda],
    [IdLinhaVenda]
FROM
    Artigos
WHERE
    RowNumber = 10;
```

*NOTE: I do not know Portuguese (other than via Google Translate), so I made some educated guesses (& assumptions) as to which columns to use.